# Meteor and FullCalendar package css is not displaying correctly

Tags: meteor, fullcalendar

Installed fullcalendar:fullcalendar@2.9.0 on my meteor project with

```
meteor add fullcalendar:fullcalendar
```

However the css won't show correctly, it is blue and funky looking compare to how it should look. see picture below.  **I created a new meteor project and tested on there and it works, i have no clue what is going on, tried deleting the local folder and rebuild still no luck..**
[image]

Comment: are there any errors in the console? Also, it might be better to ask project specific questions on the [github page](https://github.com/rgnevashev/fullcalendar/). Lastly, maybe try another package, such as [this one](https://atmospherejs.com/rzymek/fullcalendar)

Comment: @Adam No i don't get any errors unfortunately... and I tried that package as well still same results. I will try the github page.

Comment: @Adam I just tested this on another brand new project and it works! idk what is going on....

Comment: It must be a styling problem. Use the inspector to inspect the elements and see which stylesheet is messing it up - that will give you a clue as to the source of the problem

Answer (score 0):

In case this happens to others, issue turned out to be another packages CSS causing problems.